# Can't get sound to work in namespace

Tags: linux, audio, pulseaudio, namespace

I am trying to get sound to work in a linux network namespace

```
 (+) Audio --aid=1 (mp3 2ch 44100Hz)
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1090:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
[ao/alsa] Playback open error: No such file or directory
[ao/oss] Can't open audio device /dev/dsp: No such file or directory
connect(2) call to /dev/shm/jack-1000/default/jack_0 failed (err=No such file or directory)
attempt to connect to server failed
[ao/jack] cannot open server
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1090:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
couldn't open play stream: No such file or directory
[ao/sndio] can't open sndio default
[ao] Failed to initialize audio driver 'sndio'
Could not open/initialize audio device -> no sound.
Audio: no audio


Exiting... (Errors when loading file)
```

When trying to play an mp3 using mpv I get the above error.

I have tried to run the following but it does not help

```
HOME='/home/dewi' PULSE_SERVER=/run/user/$(id -u dewi)/pulse/native PULSE_COOKIE=/home/dewi/.config/pulse/cookie
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/1000"
```

Help please?

Answer (score 0):

You must **export** these variables:

```bsh
HOME='/home/dewi'
PULSE_SERVER=/run/user/$(id -u dewi)/pulse/native
PULSE_COOKIE=/home/dewi/.config/pulse/cookie
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/1000"

export HOME PULSE_SERVER PULSE_COOKIE XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
```

You can pass these variables to sudo like this:

```
ip netns exec somens sudo HOME='/home/dewi' PULSE_SERVER=/run/user/$(id -u dewi)/pulse/native PULSE_COOKIE=/home/dewi/.config/pulse/cookie XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/1000" -u dewi -- /bin/bash
```

It is better because you will not have to set and export these variables by hand on shell and it is good if you want to write a shell script.

Comment: If you only pass the variables to bash you'll have to run 2 bash instances together with sudo.

Comment: Without passing the variables to sudo, you'll have to launch a shell with sudo and set/export the variables by hand on the shell, with sudo you can just pass the variables in the command line. If you write a shell script, you'll have to do this.

ip netns exec somens sudo BLAH=blah -u someuser -- /bin/bash

Comment: It's not necessary, I already answered you, just pass the variables to sudo for running programs as a normal user (as root account does not have PulseAudio). It avoids you having to set and export the variables in the shell and it's necessary if you want to write a shell script.

Comment: Anyone can imagine that passing the variables directly to sudo is better than launching a shell as a normal user and set/export the variables by hand. It's faster and more convenient, and if you want to write a shell script, you'll need to do that.

Comment: Ok MAN, I edited and explained why it's better to pass the variables to sudo.